# Second normal form : Artificial key vs Composite Primary Key

Tags: mysql, database-normalization

I recently read about the second normal form that: "If your table has an artificial primary key and no composite primary key, it's in second normal form".
What if my table has an artificial key as well as a composite primary key in my table?
Will it be in second normal form, then also?

Comment: Where is this statement from?

Comment: @stark  Reference: HeadFirst SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A relation in which *every* candidate key consists of a single column is in 2NF. (The relational model always considers *every* candidate key.)

```
element_name  atomic_number  chem_symbol
--
Hydrogen      1              H
Helium        2              He
Lithium       3              Li
...
```

Each attribute here is a candidate key. This table is in 2NF. It's also in 3NF, BCNF, 4NF, and 5NF.

> What if my table has an artificial key as well as a composite primary key in my table? Will it be in second normal form, then also?

It depends on the non-prime attributes and *their* dependencies. If you have a non-prime attribute that's functionally dependent on part of that composite primary key, then the relation is not in 2NF.

Comment: The first sentence is wrong. All CKs simple but {} determining a non-prime attribute, ie only 1 value allowed for it, does not satisfy 2NF. (As I expect you know. So I'm surprised you don't say that.)